# How to join multiple table where two tables are based on third table

Tags: mysql

I am new in MySql and am trying to join multiple column from 4 tables where two tables (order and product) linked by third table i.e orderline.
Here is the query which I think is not correct.

```
Select orders.OrderDate, orders.OrderID, orders.OrderStatus, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, product.ProductName , product.Qunatity, branch.BranchName
from orders 
inner join customer ON orders.CustomerId = customer.CustomerId
inner join orderline ON  orderline.OrderId = orders.OrderID
inner join branch on orders.BranchID = branch.BranchID
inner join  orderline.ProductId = product.ProductId;
```

But I am getting error which of 1054, unkwon column 'product.ProductName' in 'fieldlist'
Can anyone show me the right way to do this.Thanks

Comment: You didn't join product table and fetching product table data thats why getting unknown column error...... Check last join in query....inner join  product ON  rderline.ProductId = product.ProductId;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo in the last JOIN.  Is this what you meant?

```
SELECT orders.OrderDate, orders.OrderID, orders.OrderStatus, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, product.ProductName , product.Quantity, branch.BranchName
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN customer ON orders.CustomerId = customer.CustomerId
INNER JOIN orderline ON  orderline.OrderId = orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN branch ON orders.BranchID = branch.BranchID
INNER JOIN product ON orderline.ProductId = product.ProductId;
```